# mysqli_stmt::get_result() is undefined

Tags: php, mysqli

Using php version 5.5.7, I was looking at the mysqli examples for php prepared statements: [MySQLi QuickStart Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Under example #5 they use a method call:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, label FROM test WHERE id = 1");
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

However, I cannot seem to call `get_result` in my own environment. Netbeans also does not show an autocomplete for this. Is this an actual method that I am missing, or do the examples have incorrect method names in them?

Comment: This is only available when mysqli was compiled as [mysqlnd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) (php native driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this line on the [PHP page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) for `get_result()`:

```
Available only with mysqlnd.
```

To use this you'd have to compile PHP with mysqlnd included, or include it some other way. You might find support limited on hosted systems, so you might do better to ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to be the issue.